# how to list the special directory in my debian?

Tags: shell

In my debian console, i have set a directory named `f:\workspace`

```
root@rebuild:~# ls  /root
f:\workspace
f:\workspace\data\\
f:\workspace\data\\balance
f:\workspace\data\\balance\600000
Python-3.4.0
Python-3.4.0.tgz
root@rebuild:~# ls  /root/f:\workspace
ls: cannot access /root/f:workspace: No such file or director
```

How can list the directory and file in the  `f:\workspace` in root ?

1. no error message displayed on the console.

   root@rebuild:~# ls  /root/'f:\workspace'
     root@rebuild:~# ls  '/root/f:\workspace'
     root@rebuild:~# ls  /root/f:\workspace
     root@rebuild:~# ls '/root/f:\workspace'
2. the child directory can not be listed on the console.

   f:\workspace\data\
     f:\workspace\data\balance
     f:\workspace\data\balance\600000

Comment: You could use auto-complete. Also, read about special characters in bash.

Answer (score 1):

Escape or quote the special characters so that the shell doesn't process them.

```
ls  /root/f:\\workspace
ls  /root/'f:\workspace'
ls  '/root/f:\workspace'
```

Comment: f:\workspace\data\\
f:\workspace\data\\balance
f:\workspace\data\\balance\600000 can not be listed on the console.

Comment: Then you have permission issues. This has nothing to do with `ls` or the shell.

Answer (score 1):

You can use single quote as well:

```
ls '/root/f:\workspace'
```